# Remove Columns where both rows have a non-zero number?

Tags: r, dataframe

How would I remove columns from a data frame when both rows for that column have non-zero values.

For example I want to change the following table from the following

| Dogs | Cats | Snakes | Elephants |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 2 |

to the following

| Cats | Snakes |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 |

The reason the other columns are removed is because both rows had non-zero numbers. If one of the two rows has a zero then we'd retain the entire column. It does not matter which one contains the zero.

I tried to use dyplr and if else statements but most of those are based on single conditions in the column being met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `colSums` here:

```r
df[, colSums(df!=0) != nrow(df)]

  Cats Snakes
1    0      1
2    1      0
```

The logic here is to retain any column such that the count of row values not equal to zero does *not* equal the total number of rows.  Put another way, this says to retain any column having at least one zero row.

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(Dogs=c(1,2), Cats=c(0,1), Snakes=c(1,0), Elephants=c(3,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are few other options -

```
#1. Base R Filter
Filter(function(x) any(x == 0), df)

#2. purrr::keep
purrr::keep(df, ~any(.x == 0))

#3. purrr::discard
purrr::discard(df, ~all(.x != 0))
```

All of which returns output as -

```
#  Cats Snakes
#1    0      1
#2    1      0
```

Comment: Your base solution is fastest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` solution using `select` along with `any`:

We just select columns that contain at least one 0 or less:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  select(where(~ any(. <= 0)))
```

```
  Cats Snakes
1    0      1
2    1      0
```

**Benchmark** the so far provided answers:

```
mbm <- microbenchmark(
  base_TimBiegeleisen = df[, colSums(df!=0) != nrow(df)],
  dplyr_TarJae = df %>% select(where(~ any(. <= 0))),
  base_Ronak_Shah = Filter(function(x) any(x == 0), df),
  purr_keep_Ronak_Shah = purrr::keep(df, ~any(.x == 0)),
  purr_discard_Ronak_Shah = purrr::discard(df, ~all(.x != 0)),
  times=50
)
mbm
autoplot(mbm)
```

[image]